# After Official Poll Sample Application in Django?

Tags: python, database, django

I am new to Django and I've completed the Polls app tutorial successfully. What I want to do now **FROM THE USER SIDE** is the following:

1. Create poll
2. Delete poll
3. Edit the question in a specific poll
4. Add a choice to the poll
5. Remove a choice from a poll

I want to do all this from the user side.

I don't have knowledge in Python, but I learn quickly and I know Java pretty well.
I at least need a guide to know how to start doing any of these tasks and I'll continue the rest.

What do you suppose I shall do? Any tutorials or any helpful links?

Comment: What does "**FROM THE USER SIDE**" mean?

Comment: I think he's asking how to build a user-interface.

Comment: @Furbeenator yes exactly

Comment: A snarky answer would be, Go to Django Admin. This is a really open-ended question. This really doesn't require much Python, you are going to do most of if through the Django framework. Mostly, you'll need to know how to build HTML pages, review AJAX, jQuery, and Javascript. Then you'll need to learn how to use Django Templates to create those pages with an interface to the data to edit. You can build Django Forms really easily, to keep it "simple." Go to `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/` and study up the Forms API. When ready, Google "jQuery tutorial."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're new to a django here is a good reference after the sample tutorial [Here](http://elleestcrimi.me/2012/03/15/introduction-django-guestbook-application/)